# How to tune QAOAAnsatz when solution is known to have a certain form?

Tags: qiskit, qaoa

I'm running `QAOAAnsatz` in `QisKit`, and I know that the solution to my problem has a certain form.  Namely:

```
x=100010001
```

You can think of `x` as a flattened square matrix, with exactly one `1` in each row, and each column.  E.g.:

```
x=
100
010
001
```

Since I know that the optimal solution will take this form, I wonder if there is a way to help `QAOAAnsatz` find this solution, since I know that the solution will take this form.